# Is there a way to sort test run results by time in Testrail?

Tags: testrail

We use Testrail for test case management. I want to be able to sort the test run results by the execution time of the test cases. Is this possible?
The only way I can see the execution time of the test case is if I open each test case instance individually.

Answer (score 0):

When you have your test run result page you can click on the right side on the column icon and add the elapsed column to your table. Then you can sort on that column